# Two simultaneous maximum values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm quite new to DB/queries and so on, so my apologies if the question I'm about to ask is very basic.

I've got two tables: "charging" and "taxes". Off of the first there's two fields to pick: "invoiceNumber" and "sequentialInvoice" and on the latter, three: "sequentialObligation", "sequentialTax" and "reference".

"invoiceNumber" on first table = "reference" on second (used to match both tables)

What I need is: for all the cases where there are duplicates of "invoiceNumber" and "sequentialInvoice", obtain **only the maximum** of "sequentialObligation" and it's corresponding "sequentialTax" value.

The query I've ran:

```
select CHA.invoiceNumber, CHA.sequentialInvoice, TAX.sequentialTax,max(TAX.sequentialObligation)  
from charging CHA, taxes TAX  
where CHA.CEMPTITU = 1 and CHA.invoiceNumber = TAX.reference and CHA.CEMPTITU = TAX.CEMPTITU  
group by CHA.invoiceNumber, CHA.sequentialInvoice, TAX.sequentialObligation, TAX.sequentialTax  
having count(CHA.invoiceNumber) >1
```

The query returns

```
invoiceNumber sequentialInvoice sequentialTax max(tax.sequentalObligation)
441001970973         6537           12               3
441001970973         6537           16               2
```

etc.
And should only return the first row. What am I doing wrong?

PS: Apologies if it's too ugly; I swear I tried to explain it as simply as I could.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using analytic functions here.  Define a partition on the invoice number and sequential invoice.  Then, report only records having more than one record per partition, also having the highest sequential obligation value.

```
SELECT
    invoiceNumber,
    sequentialInvoice,
    sequentialTax,
    sequentialObligation
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CHA.invoiceNumber,
        CHA.sequentialInvoice,
        TAX.sequentialTax,
        TAX.sequentialObligation,
        COUNT(CHA.invoiceNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY CHA.invoiceNumber,
            CHA.sequentialInvoice) cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CHA.invoiceNumber, CHA.sequentialInvoice
            ORDER BY TAX.sequentialObligation DESC) rn
    FROM charging CHA
    INNER JOIN taxes TAX
        ON CHA.invoiceNumber = TAX.reference AND
           CHA.CEMPTITU = TAX.CEMPTITU
    WHERE CHA.CEMPTITU = 1
) t
WHERE
    cnt > 1 AND rn = 1
```